# finding the longest line using trees

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm working on finding the largest line using trees for a fish; Is there any way to avoid fins, and find the longest from head to tail?

Currently the 2 points which are located using the maximum distance lies on one of fish's fin and other on the tail; but I need the 2 points on head and tail to calculate the largest line.

```
binary_fish = cv2.imread('/content/fish4-masked.jpg', cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)

# Step 1: Preprocessing
# Apply erosion and dilation to the binary fish image
kernel = np.ones((3, 3), np.uint8)
binary_fish = cv2.erode(binary_fish, kernel, iterations=1)
binary_fish = cv2.dilate(binary_fish, kernel, iterations=1)

# Step 2: Threshold to create a binary image
_, binary_fish = cv2.threshold(binary_fish, 128, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY)

# Step 3: Skeletonize the binary fish image
skeleton = morphology.skeletonize(binary_fish > 0)

# Step 4: Find the centerline from the skeleton
skeleton = skeleton.astype(np.uint8) * 255

# Find the contours of the skeleton
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(skeleton, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)

# Extract the largest contour (assuming it's the centerline)
centerline = max(contours, key=cv2.contourArea)

# Create a blank canvas
height, width = binary_fish.shape
centerline_image = np.zeros((height, width), dtype=np.uint8)

# Draw the centerline on the canvas
cv2.drawContours(centerline_image, [centerline], -1, 255, 1)

# Find the coordinates of the points on the centerline
points = centerline.squeeze(axis=1) 

max_distance = 0
farthest_points = (0, 0), (0, 0)

# Calculate pairwise distances and find the two farthest points
for i in range(len(points)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(points)):
        x1, y1 = points[i]
        x2, y2 = points[j]
        distance = math.sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
        
        if distance > max_distance:
            max_distance = distance
            farthest_points = (x1, y1), (x2, y2)

farthest_point1, farthest_point2 = farthest_points

radius = 5  # Radius of the circle
color = (0, 255, 0)  # Green color (you can choose a different color)
thickness = -1  # Fill the circle

# Draw the first farthest point
cv2.circle(original_fish, farthest_point1, radius, color, thickness)

# Draw the second farthest point
cv2.circle(original_fish, farthest_point2, radius, color, thickness)
```

[Skeleton Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50x3y.png)
[2-point Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cXi94.png)

I have implemented skeletonization to find the skeleton; due to fins we have extra branches attached to the skeleton centerline.

Comment: Erode a bunch to get rid of the fins and then do the skeleton 2 point thing?

Comment: Please put your `import` statements back in so that folks don't have to guess what packages you are using.

Comment: It's unspecific. Research more and define a logic to distinguish fins from other parts. Also post an original image. It's hard to believe it's a fish. It's like a snail.

Comment: @MarkSetchell; I used the SAM model to segment fish and mask so that I can find the principal center axis line; Is there any way to remove those branches?

Comment: Maybe try morphological opening (erosion followed by dilation) to get rid of the *"antennae"* and *"horn"* - P.S. I don't know fishy terms.